# Excel advanced multiple columns match

Tags: excel

I have 2 tables in Excel with several columns.
I would like to look in one table for all rows that have 2 columns with the same value as the 2 other columns of the first table.

Example.

Table 1:

```
A1  A2  other columns....
02  AH
02L 
0A  0D
0D  0O
0O  1X
0WK 2K
1X  
02  2U
02L 2X
0A  3B
```

and table 2 :

```
A1  A2  other oclumns...
02  AH
02L AI
0A  AM
02  AP
02L 
0A  AP
2K  AR
2N  AS
1X  AS
02  AP
```

So for instance I would like to check in table 1 all the rows the have a match in table 2, meaning the same value in A1 and A2.
The outcome can be just the word Match, to indicate that this line has a match in the second table.

Thank you for your help.
Paul

Comment: Can you put an example the desired outcome?

Comment: Hi Tim,
Well the outcome could be just a word saying this line has a match, that would be enough for me.
Thx !

Comment: Can you use a helper column? Can you add matching examples, so `02 AH` will match with `02 AH` in table 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array formula:

```
{=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1&B1, Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B, 1, FALSE), "Not Found")}
```

Entered with `SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER`.

Alternatively use a helper column in the second Table

```
A   B   C
02  AH  =A1&B1
02L AI  =A2&B2
0A  AM  =A3&B3
```

Then you can use

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1&B1, Sheet2!C:C, 1, FALSE), "Not Found")
```

To avoid using an array formula.